# Is a mysql LIKE statement with an escaped string containing unescaped wildcards '%' (percent) or '_' (underscore) vulnerable?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, wildcard, sql-like

Let's say we have the following code (for some kind of search or similar):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('%' . $username . '%'));
```

The username supplied is properly escaped, but the characters `%`(= 0 or more arbitrary characters) and `_` (= exactly 1 arbitrary characters) get interpreted as a wildcard by MySQL.

I understand that users could enter the `%` or the `_` for a search and I should escape it if I want the search function to work properly. (In cases like `set_pt` and getting `setopt` in the result).

But my question is: Could someone exploit this? If yes, how could someone exploit this and how to prevent it? Would the function below suffice?

```
function escape_like_string($str) {
  return str_replace(Array('%', '_'), Array('\%', '\_'), $str);
}
```

One possibility I could think of would be by entering tons of `%`, so the server would need to allocate a lot of memory. Would this work?

Comment: It is not "vulnerable" from an SQLi point of view but it will change the semantic meaning of the query term. It's easy enough to sort out though, you just `str_replace()` them (since this is not a security problem as such, this simple solution is fine). You are already using prepared statements, so SQLi is not possible, *although*... since you are using PDO-MySQL, you **must** disable emulated prepares or your code is subject to the same SQLi edge-case hole that `mysql_real_escape_string()` has.

Comment: @ATaylor From [php.net/mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string): **Note**: `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not escape `%`  and `_`. These are wildcards in MySQL if combined with `LIKE`, `GRANT`, or `REVOKE`.

Comment: @Mogria Which is why I deleted my comment. I read the same line ;)

Comment: To escape strings use `addcslashes($str, '%_');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone exploit this?

For SQL-injection? No.

For an easter-egg like behavior? Probably. In this case, if you don't want let your users use wildcards in this search, you can do 2 things:

1. proper escape wildcards (and the escape character),

   ```
   str_replace(array('\\', '%', '_'), array('\\\\', '\\%', '\\_'), $str);
   // or:
   str_replace(array('|', '%', '_'), array('||', '|%', '|_'), $str);
   // with SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ? ESCAPE '|'
   ```
2. or use `LOCATE(substr, str) > 0` to find exact matches.